# Is there a function that anybody might be familiar with that will create a square kagome lattice with periodic boundary conditions using Networkx?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a square kagome lattice with periodic boundary conditions using Networkx. Once this is successful I would like to pass this graph to Netket for further use.

I have tried using quantipy as they mention having a square kagome lattice function in their documentation quantipy.lattice.Squagome(a=1.0, simulation_torus=None, **kwargs). However when I attempt to call this function I get an error saying it doesn't exist.

For the time being I am brute forcing the creation of the square kagome lattice using Networkx by defining each node and edge individually which is both not efficient and ugly. In addition, using this method won't allow for periodic boundary conditions.

Here is the brute force I was using to make the lattice:

```
import netket as nk
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Define a custom 2D square kagome lattice using networkx to generate the graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1,pos=(0,0))
G.add_node(2,pos=(1,0))
G.add_node(3,pos=(2,0))
G.add_node(4,pos=(3,0))
G.add_node(5,pos=(4,0))
G.add_node(6,pos=(5,0))
G.add_node(7,pos=(6,0))
G.add_node(8,pos=(0,1))
G.add_node(9,pos=(2,1))
G.add_node(10,pos=(4,1))
G.add_node(11,pos=(6,1))
G.add_node(12,pos=(0,2))
G.add_node(13,pos=(1,2))
G.add_node(14,pos=(2,2))
G.add_node(15,pos=(3,2))
G.add_node(16,pos=(4,2))
G.add_node(17,pos=(5,2))
G.add_node(18,pos=(6,2))
G.add_node(19,pos=(0,3))
G.add_node(20,pos=(2,3))
G.add_node(21,pos=(4,3))
G.add_node(22,pos=(6,3))
G.add_node(23,pos=(0,4))
G.add_node(24,pos=(1,4))
G.add_node(25,pos=(2,4))
G.add_node(26,pos=(3,4))
G.add_node(27,pos=(4,4))
G.add_node(28,pos=(5,4))
G.add_node(29,pos=(6,4))
G.add_node(30,pos=(0,5))
G.add_node(31,pos=(2,5))
G.add_node(32,pos=(4,5))
G.add_node(33,pos=(6,5))
G.add_node(34,pos=(0,6))
G.add_node(35,pos=(1,6))
G.add_node(36,pos=(2,6))
G.add_node(37,pos=(3,6))
G.add_node(38,pos=(4,6))
G.add_node(39,pos=(5,6))
G.add_node(40,pos=(6,6))

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(2,3)
G.add_edge(3,4)
G.add_edge(4,5)
G.add_edge(5,6)
G.add_edge(6,7)
G.add_edge(12,13)
G.add_edge(13,14)
G.add_edge(14,15)
G.add_edge(15,16)
G.add_edge(16,17)
G.add_edge(17,18)
G.add_edge(23,24)
G.add_edge(24,25)
G.add_edge(25,26)
G.add_edge(26,27)
G.add_edge(27,28)
G.add_edge(28,29)
G.add_edge(34,35)
G.add_edge(35,36)
G.add_edge(36,37)
G.add_edge(37,38)
G.add_edge(38,39)
G.add_edge(39,40)
G.add_edge(1,8)
G.add_edge(8,12)
G.add_edge(12,19)
G.add_edge(19,23)
G.add_edge(23,30)
G.add_edge(30,34)
G.add_edge(3,9)
G.add_edge(9,14)
G.add_edge(14,20)
G.add_edge(20,25)
G.add_edge(25,31)
G.add_edge(31,36)
G.add_edge(5,10)
G.add_edge(10,16)
G.add_edge(16,21)
G.add_edge(21,27)
G.add_edge(27,32)
G.add_edge(32,38)
G.add_edge(7,11)
G.add_edge(11,18)
G.add_edge(18,22)
G.add_edge(22,29)
G.add_edge(29,33)
G.add_edge(33,40)


#Pass the graph from networkx to NetKet custom graph
pos = nk.graph.CustomGraph(list(G.edges))
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. You need to show us what you did and what problems you faced when you did